# JQuery autocompleted does not clear the input after select

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want my input field to be cleared after the user select the input from the autocopmleted I have searched for answers on stackoverflow and none of the answers work for me. 
Here is my code:

```
  $("#fastSearchInput").autocomplete({   
                    source: users,
                    select: function (suggestion, ui)
                    {
                        id = ui.item.data;
                       window.open("member.php?id="+id,'_blank');
                       $(this).val("");
                       event.preventDefault();
                    }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your select handler's first parameter to `event`. E.G

```
$("#fastSearchInput").autocomplete({   
  source: users,
  select: function (event, ui)
  {
    id = ui.item.data;
    window.open("member.php?id="+id,'_blank');
    $(this).val("");
    event.preventDefault();
  }});
```

Comment: @dasdasd it happens